# My #build method is not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope I explain this well. I am trying to build a form in my rails app to create a flight, and assign a pilot to it. I keep getting a "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass" message.

Here is my flight model

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :pilot
    belongs_to :passenger
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pilot

end
```

and here is my pilot model

```
class Pilot < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :flights
    has_many :pilots, through: :flights
    
    
end
```

**I suspect btw it might have something to do with the way my relationships are setup but having a hard time proving that.**

This is what I have for my #new method within my FlightsController when I first started making it

```
def new
        @flight = Flight.new
        @flight.pilot.build
end
```

But I did move the "@flight.pilot.build" line to my #create method at first since that's where its saving it to the database, but it was still giving me the same "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass"

```
def create
        @flight = Flight.create(flight_params)
        @flight.pilot.build
        if @flight.save
            redirect_to flight_path(@flight)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end


private

    def flight_params
        params.require(:flight).permit(:flight_number, :destination, pilot_attributes: [:name, :rank])
    end
```

Here is the view I am trying to perform the create flight task on.

```
<h1>Create New Flight</h1>

<%= form_for(@flight) do |f|%>
<div>
<%= f.label :flight_number %>
<%= f.text_field :flight_number %>
</div><br>

<div>
<%= f.label :destination %>
<%= f.text_field :destination %>
</div><br>

<div>
<label for="flight_pilot_id">Assign a pilot:</label>
<%= f.collection_select :pilot_id, Pilot.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select a Pilot"} %>
</div><br>


    <h3>Or Create new Pilot:</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :pilot, Pilot.new do |pilot_attributes|%>
        <%= pilot_attributes.label :name, "Pilot name:" %>
        <%= pilot_attributes.text_field :name %>
        <br>
        <%= pilot_attributes.label :rank, "Rank:" %>
        <%= pilot_attributes.text_field :rank %>
        <br>
    <% end %>



<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `has_many` assocations you cannot create new instances off a `has_one/belongs_to` assocation since it is nil when you haven't assigned the association.

Instead the [`has_one/belongs_to` class methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) generate the following methods:

```
                                  |            |  belongs_to  |
generated methods                 | belongs_to | :polymorphic | has_one
----------------------------------+------------+--------------+---------
other                             |     X      |      X       |    X
other=(other)                     |     X      |      X       |    X
build_other(attributes={})        |     X      |              |    X
create_other(attributes={})       |     X      |              |    X
create_other!(attributes={})      |     X      |              |    X
reload_other                      |     X      |      X       |    X
```

Your controller should actually read:

```
def new
  @flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
  # this just seeds the inputs
  @flight.build_pilot 
end

def create
  @flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
  if @flight.save
    redirect_to @flight
  else
    # this just seeds the inputs
    @flight.build_pilot unless @flight.pilot 
    render :new
  end
end
```

As you can see here building really has very little to do with inserting into the database. Instead it just populates the fields in the form which will not be present if the association is nil. Nested attributes takes care of actually creating the Flight record. Don't provide the second parameter to `fields_for` as that does not provide a default - it will overwrite whatever existing record was there.

```
<%= f.fields_for :pilot do |pilot_attributes| %>
  <%= pilot_attributes.label :name, "Pilot name:" %>
  <%= pilot_attributes.text_field :name %>
  <br>
  <%= pilot_attributes.label :rank, "Rank:" %>
  <%= pilot_attributes.text_field :rank %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

If you want to assign existing records you just need to pass and whitelist the `pilot_id` parameter:

```
<%= form_with(model: @flight) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:pilot_id, Pilot.all, :name, :id) %>
<% end %>
```

```
def flight_params
  # be nice to maintainers and don't write your strong parameters 
  # in one mega-line
  params.require(:flight)
        .permit(
          :flight_number, :destination, :pilot_id,
          pilot_attributes: [:name, :rank]
        )
end
```

However this can cause issues if the user passes both the pilot_id and nested attributes so you'll need to deal with that eventuality.

Answer (score -1):

`belongs_to` association returns a related object or `nil`.
In your case, you use nested attributes for `pilot`. You need to remove `@flight.pilot.build` then a pilot will be created from `flight_params` when you call `Flight.create(flight_params)`. It might depend on your Rails version, you need to check your model `Flight` setup to have [`accepts_nested_attributes_for :pilot`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Also, I believe you need to have `pilot_id` in `flight_params` to be able to assign an existing pilot.

```
params.require(:flight).permit(:flight_number, :destination, :pilot_id, pilot_attributes: [:name, :rank])
```

Comment: I need to google how to determine if my model accepts the nested attri's. I figured that, and the fact it's a belongs_to relationship might be where my issue is. Thank you sir.

Comment: And I think it's not setting the pilot_id, because it keeps bouncing back to the new view.

Comment: `pilot_id` for a case when you choose an existing one. In both cases, you don't need `@flight.pilot.build` I reckon.

Comment: Ok because somewhere there needs to to be for example... @pilot.id = pilot_id upon the creation of a pilot then in the case of selecting an existing pilot, hence the pilot_id....I am just thinking out loud btw. Sorry if I am all over the place.